# Webpack Dev Server: Support multiple hosts

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

[Webpack Dev Server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) defaults to using localhost as its host.  This can easily be overwritten by specifying the `host` parameter with either a `hostname` or `IP address`.  However, it seems that you can only specify one.  For example, if I specify the IP Address `192.168.1.20`, then it stops responding to `localhost`.  How can I configure Webpack Dev Server to listen to multiple hosts?

Comment: You were able to find it?

Comment: @phkavitha: I started a discussion here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/400.  If you can chime in with your feedback, that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is the catch-all `host` and will bind to all hosts.

Example:

```
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/400#issuecomment-201213206